# Read and write image data

Tags: c#, image, stream

I have been programming a map editor to use when making 2D games. I have nearly completed it, however I can't load maps.

I have multiple options for saving and loading maps. I have:

DAT File
BIN File
MAP File
XML File

XML isn't the issue but the other file types are. I need to be able to read and write image data to these other 3 file types. I would suggest just removing these file types, but sometimes having maps that aren't XML are useful.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not asking to follow an algorithm that is already produced. What I mean is to write the image data to a file, and then read the data back into a bitmap object.

Comment: Need more information about the format of DAT, BIN, and MAP files.  Do you just need to know how to open and read these files?  Do you need pointers on how to parse them?

Comment: I've used these file types before when saving very simple data, like strings and integers.

Comment: Are these actually common file types? If so, there must be definitions and format descriptions. Can you or anybody provide the links? I didn't find anything on the 1st few hits.. - Found http://gamedev.stackexchange.com though..

Comment: BIN file - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file, DAT File - http://pc.net/extensions/file/dat MAP File - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAP_%28file_format%29

Comment: @HarrisonPickering Your question is very vague but even if you update it, it'll likely be off-topic. For each file format, you should search for format documentation and then implement that format for reading/writing. You can find documentation for many file formats here: http://www.wotsit.org/

Comment: @HarrisonPickering `.dat`, `.bin` files are typically just generic names for some documented (or possibly proprietary) file formats. Many games have `.dat` files but they may actually be in different actual file formats, whatever is most convenient for the type of data held in a particular file.

Comment: @HarrisonPickering : I can't undo the upvote on the comment with the links you provided any longer but __all those links__ only prove that __none of these formats__ are really estblished formats you can expect to open, when they come from any other source than your own application.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're talking about is having a proprietary format for your game map data.

What you want to do is take a look at Object Relational Mapping (you could start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  You want to come up with a good way to structure your object (map image) in a store (a binary file).  You'll want to write up some kind of class that follows this kind of interface:

```
public interface ORMap
{
    public void Save(MyMap map, string fileIdentifier);
}
```

It sounds like you've already done this for XML.

You could the implement that interface to transform and/or serialize your MyMap object to the desired format and write it to disk using fileIdentifier as the name.

There is no one standard way of doing this, but if you have examples from other similar games you could try to look at their API and/or file structure and imitate it.